# Gmail oauth imap php implementation

Tags: php, api, oauth, gmail, imap

Guyz please, is there any simple php "not involving zend" example on how to use oauth with imap to get full control over gmail, it seems that oauth2.0 is not implemented yet with imap. All the documentation is currently with zend, however im developing my apps with simple php. Can I have at least a step by step algorithm? Thanks in advance

Comment: why not use zend component? You don't need to include whole zend library. any reason why you use zend?

Comment: Because It didn't work for me, and I will need to merge it with other services already written in simple php, so I will need to have the whole project as simple php one.

Comment: This is a FULL implementation of standard PHP IMAP functions like (imap_open, imap_getmailboxes, imap_*, etc...)

https://github.com/ddeboer/imap/issues/443#issuecomment-1172158902

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implemented a simple library.

Delete mail function is not yet added. But you can take a look if it satisfies your need. 

Try example.
https://github.com/vmuthal/VivOAuthIMAP

Comment: Works Like a charm, thanks for posting it, Im sure more people will find it useful !

Comment: @FaouziFJTech My solution is more compliant with PHP IMAP standard. Read this post for support https://github.com/ddeboer/imap/issues/443#issuecomment-1172158902

Answer (score 2):

YES YES and YES. Must of spent 8 hours trying to come up with a solution that would allow me to access Gmail from "simple" php, using oauth (as part of a larger email application that spends most of its time talking to non-gmail pop servers).

Notes:

- many simple imap_open to gmail solutions can work IF you enable Google's "less secure"  mode, using  https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps  ... of course, that means your gmail is less secure.
- vivOAuthIMAP will work in either mode: "normal" logon if "less secure" is enabled, Oauth logon if less secure is disabled.
- for VivOAuthIMAP to work, be sure to enable php_curl

*Lots of almost-there solutions that just didn't quite work for me (who works in simple php). Here are some of the sites that sort of almost yield something useful:

- http://codeload.github.com/google/google-api-php-client/zip/master -- the examples worked, and I was able to use idtoken.php to obtain an access token, but it didn't work with ...
- http:// code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/wiki/PhpSampleCode -- when I cut/pasted the access token generated by idtoken (from above), I got a login failure.  I do wonder that I did wrong
- http://  www.phpclasses.org/browse/download/zip/package/7700/name/oauth-api-2014-12-22.zip  -- didn't quite work